# Disconnect call programmatically in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, core-telephony

I want to disconnect a phone call programatically in `iOS7`. I know we can [programmatically handle the interruptions](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/02/programmatically-handling-ipho.html) for Incoming calls, SMS etc. on iPhone (without Appstore).

I have to create a [launch daemon](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/) to get notifications as [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't deliver the notifications to `UIApplications` in the background as explained by **Nate** in his [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236454/1603072).

**Nate**'s comments shows there is some scope of disconnecting certain calls on an iPhone using the launch daemon (without Appstore).

So, My first question is it possible ? and if it is then How to do ?

**Note :** *My App is not going to be on AppStore.*

Comment: i don't think there's a stable jailbreak out for iOS7 yet, so that makes this difficult

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's not possible in iOS7. You need special entitlement so until there will be a jailbreak you are out of luck