# Display CFUserNotification on iPhone lock screen

Tags: ios, notifications, lockscreen, springboard, alertview

I am developing an iPhone app that need to display some message on lock screen. I have tried to use local notification or CFUserNotification but neither of them can display the message on top of the lock screen. For CFUserNotification I have tried kCFUserNotificationAlertTopMostKey (refer [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199642/display-cfusernotificationdisplayalert-on-iphone-lock-screen?answertab=active#tab-top)) but it still not work.  I am not going to hook springboard since my phone is not jailbreak. I have found an app do implement it and I have tested on my none-jailbreak iPhone iOS 6.0, don't know how to implement this.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFUserNotificationAlertTopMostKey];`

It does work